# Where are the controls for .aspx pages?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I had purchased a VoIP software that is written in C#/.NET/ASPX and wanted to edit some of the forms. I found that there are several files ending in: .wuc, .cs, .aspx. By the way, I've no knowledge of .Net/aspx. Recently I wanted to change a form and opened the aspx file and was almost empty and had this:

```
<%@
Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SpeedDial.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="CCEstore.SD_SpeedDial" MasterPageFile="mainService.master"
%>
```

There was also, SpeedDial.wuc file, which had some asp form tags but didn't display anything. I want to know where the files ending in .CS may be. Is there way to modify the forms inside those pages and find .cs files which are'nt there?

Comment: Before wanting to change .net files did you try to learn about .NET first?

Answer (score 2):

The code behind for the controls have been compiled and are contained in an assembly in the product's BIN folder.

See [Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).